# how to make a horizontal bar graph through chart.js in which bar are right align on y-axies

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, victory-charts

I want to make a horizontal bar graph in which bars are right aligned and extent toward left side according to the value. Here is the link of [horizontal bar graph](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) of chart.js but in this bar extended from left to right side but i want my bars to extend from right to left side and i am unable to find any option to change bar sides.

i have tried this [solution](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) but unable to find any option to change bars directions. And i also tried this [solution](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-bar#horizontal) by using victor.js library for this but no result.

Comment: In chart,js you only have to set the option `scales.x.reverse: true` (`scales:{x: {reverse: true}}`)